# Fragment does not show update done from BottomSheetFragment (Room + Viewmodel)

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-room, viewmodel

I have ToDoList Application , when I press items of recycler the bottomsheetfragment (ModifyFragment) shows my selected task to do modifying works. but updating process is not done since I leave Home Fragment and recreate.But if I leave app and come back again (when oncreate works again) I can see my changes.  I am sharing my codes :

```
My TaskViewModel ( which is sharedviewmodel for both my home fragment and my bottom sheet fragment : 

@HiltViewModel
class TaskViewModel @Inject constructor(private var tRepo: TaskRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val notesList = MutableLiveData<List<Task>>()


    init {
        loadAllTask()
    }

     fun loadAllTask() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            notesList.postValue(tRepo.getAllTask())
        }
    }

    fun delete(task: Task) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        tRepo.delete(task)
        loadAllTask()
    }

    fun update(task: Task) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch{
        tRepo.update(task)
    }

     fun search(searchText : String)   = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
         notesList.value = tRepo.search(searchText)
     }

}
```

My Bottom Sheet fragment :

```
class ModifyFragment(val task: Task) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentModifyBinding
    private val viewModel: TaskViewModel by activityViewModels()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentModifyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


        val date = task.date
        val priority = task.priority
        val taskCurrent = task.task

        binding.date.text = date
        binding.task.setText(taskCurrent)
        binding.add.setOnClickListener {
            val task = Task(task.id,priority,binding.task.text.toString(),task.date,task.isDone)
            viewModel.update(task)
            dismiss()
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Home Fragment :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var viewmodel: TaskViewModel
  
 

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)


        val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerDays)

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.toSave)
        }
        
        binding.search.setOnQueryTextListener(object : OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                query?.let { viewmodel.search(it) }
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                newText?.let { viewmodel.search(it) }
                return true
            }
        })

        val adapter = TaskAdapter(requireContext(), emptyList(), viewmodel, this)
        binding.recyclerTask.adapter = adapter
        viewmodel.notesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Log.e("tag","observer")
            adapter.updateList(it)
        }

        return binding.root
    }
```

Additionally I want to share my adapter also , I have used updateList method (maybe problem is that) because in other way view model was not observing my changes , when I want to create new task.  Adapter :

```
class TaskAdapter(private val mContext : Context, private var list : List<Task>, private val viewModel: TaskViewModel, private val fragment : Fragment) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskDesignHolder>(){


    inner class TaskDesignHolder( val binding : TaskItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskDesignHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = TaskItemBinding.inflate(inflater,parent,false)
        return TaskDesignHolder(binding)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskDesignHolder, position: Int) {

        val b = holder.binding
        val itemlist = list[position]

        b.task.text = itemlist.task
        b.time.text = itemlist.date
        if (itemlist.isDone){
            b.task.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            b.time.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            b.checkbox.isChecked = true
        }
        b.root.setOnClickListener{
            if (!itemlist.isDone) {
                val bottomSheetFragment = ModifyFragment(itemlist)
                bottomSheetFragment.show(fragment.childFragmentManager, bottomSheetFragment.tag)
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"You can't modify finished tasks.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        b.priority.backgroundTintList = when(itemlist.priority){
            "Low" -> ContextCompat.getColorStateList(mContext, R.color.green)
            "Medium" -> ContextCompat.getColorStateList(mContext, R.color.yellow)
            "High" -> ContextCompat.getColorStateList(mContext, R.color.red)
            else -> ContextCompat.getColorStateList(mContext, R.color.green)

        }

        b.delete.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.delete(itemlist)
        }

        b.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked){
                b.task.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
                b.time.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
                val task = Task(itemlist.id,itemlist.priority,itemlist.task,itemlist.date,true)
                viewModel.update(task)
            }
            else{
                b.task.paintFlags = 0
                b.time.paintFlags = 0
                val task = Task(itemlist.id,itemlist.priority,itemlist.task,itemlist.date,false)
                viewModel.update(task)
            }
        }



    }
    fun updateList(list : List<Task>){
        this.list = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

I have tried to get my data with OnResume , and also called loadAllTask in my update function to retrieve again. not worked.

Comment: I think your repository doesn't expose a LiveData/Flow as output for getAllTasks. So that, whenever you modify your data the ViewModel won't be notified. I'm not sure if you are using a DB in your repo, if so, try to make the query results reactive. Check this out: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#6

Comment: Thanks !  I was using LiveData , changed it to Flow . It worked .

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues with your VM and DI, the former being the one to blame here. Your TaskViewmodel is not instantiated in your HomeFragment.
You should instantiate it the same way as in your first fragment.

private val viewModel: TaskViewModel by activityViewModels()

You should also remember to annotate your fragments with @AndroidEntryPoint if you plan to inject an object into it. Otherwise your app can crash.